# CSS Grid table : How to align Headers / Subheaders with table lines

Tags: css, reactjs

I can't figure out how to align my headers / subheaders with my table lines !

I have a table, made with react. the table is made with two loops :

One for the headers and subheaders if needed, and then, one for creating and populate the lines.

My table can contain (or not !) subheaders, and each column can contain between one and 8 subheaders.

when it has these subheeaders, then the lines must be aligned with subheaders, as if it was one single table. if everything was in the same place, it could be very simple to align all with a css grid. but it is not !

here is my code pen to show you how it's broken . see that subheaders are aligned but line are not aligne at all with subheaders !
I understand very well WHY it's broken, because the minmax causes the problem. But for the moment, I can't find a rule that says : "**hey line, take exactly the same width as subheaders please ! "** because that's exactly what I want !

https://codepen.io/ciloow/pen/bGOmJev

If you have any idea on how to manage this with a css grid ideally, it would be super great !

Below, an extract of code of the codepen :

```html
<div class="table-container">
  <div class="h-table h-table--with-subheaders">
    <div class="h-table-head">
      <div class="h-table-head-cell">
        <div class="h-table-header">produit</div>
        <div class="h-table-subheader-container">
          <div class="h-table-subheader">fournisseur</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="h-table-head-cell">
        <div class="h-table-header">fournisseur</div>
        <div class="h-table-subheader-container">
          <div class="h-table-subheader">fournisseur</div>
          <div class="h-table-subheader numeric-column">fournisseur</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="h-table-head-cell">
        <div class="h-table-header">commande</div>
        <div class="h-table-subheader-container">
          <div class="h-table-subheader">fournisseur</div>
          <div class="h-table-subheader numeric-column">fournisseur</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="h-table-head-cell">
        <div class="h-table-header">statut</div>
        <div class="h-table-subheader-container">
          <div class="h-table-subheader">fournisseur</div>
          <div class="h-table-subheader numeric-column">fournisseur</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="h-table-body">
      <div class="h-table-line">
        <div class="h-table-cell h-table-cell--important">2022-A</div>
        <div class="h-table-cell">Cee183</div>
        <div class="h-table-cell numeric-value">31/02/2023 11:38:30</div>
        <div class="h-table-cell">Maison plain pied</div>
        <div class="h-table-cell numeric-value">1 299,99€</div>
        <div class="h-table-cell"><span class="solution solution--a">Exemple</span></div>
        <div class="h-table-cell numeric-value"><span class="status status--active">
            <p>Commande générée</p>
          </span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and css :

```css
.h-table {
    display: grid;

    &-head, &-line {
        display: grid;
        grid-auto-columns: minmax(0, 1fr);
        grid-auto-flow: column;
    }

    &--with-subheaders {
        .h-table-header {
            text-align: center;
        } 
    }

    .h-table-head {
        background-color: #3287F0;
        
        &-cell {
            border-right: 1px solid;
            border-color: white;

            &:last-child {
                border-right: 0;
            }
        }

        .h-table-header {
            padding: 24px 16px;
            @include typo('Open Sans', 12px, 700, 18px);
            color: white;
        }

        .h-table-subheader-container {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-around;
            @include typo('open sans', 12px, 400, 18px);

            .h-table-subheader {
                padding: 24px 16px;
                background-color: lightblue;
                flex: 1;
            }
        }
    }

    .h-table-body {
      @include typo('open sans', 12px, 400, 18px);

        .h-table-cell {
            padding: 16px;

            &.numeric-value {
                text-align: right;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: remove the divs h-table-head and h-table-body from the HTML

Comment: you can use flexbox and then set the justify-content to Space-between

Comment: removing h-table-head and h-table-body won't solve the problem, it creates a grid, but none of the data line would be aligned witht heir subheaders